# How would I find the top 10 values of a row every 100 values?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

So I have a 1 x 7000 matrix  and I am wanting to to find the top 10 values of for every 100th 'sample' group of values, and replace all other values with a zero.

I have a code that works for finding the top 10 values of the whole row:

```
[sortvals, sortidx] = sort(A,2,'descend');
B = zeros(size(A),classA));
for K = 1 : size(A,1)
    B(K,sortidx(K,1:10)) = sortvals(K,1:10);
end
```

But I can't think of how to implement this for every 100 values except maybe a brute method of splitting, finding the values, then appending but that seems needlessly messy.

Comment: The matrix ix 1x7000. What do you mean by _every 100th 'sample' group of values_? Also, if `A` is 1x7000 what's the purpose of `for K = 1 : size(A,1)`?

Answer (score 2):

[Reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) `A` into a matrix with 100 rows (and adjust the columns accordingly) and then apply [`maxk`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/maxk.html) to find the indices of top 10 elements of each column. Convert these to linear indices of `A` and extract the elements at those indices.

```
%Extract top 10 values in every 100 values
top = 10;   every = 100;
%Reshape into a 100*x matrix
tmp =  reshape(A, every, []);
%Find row subscripts of required max values
[~, ind] = maxk(tmp,top);
%Convert row subscripts to linear indices
LinIdx = (0:every:(size(tmp,2)-1)*every) + ind;
%Initialize a matrix with all zeros of the same size and class as that of A
B = zeros(size(A), classA);
%Insert the top values 
B(LinIdx) = A(LinIdx);
```